# When I add a new element in Arraylist its replace all the current element?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

i have a problem, when i add a new element which is a data class to arraylist, it's always replace the current element with the new elements. Can you give me a insight what's the problem and what's the solution. Thanks in advance

**Model**

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class ScheduleModel(

    @field:SerializedName("user_available_id")
    var userAvailableId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("teacher_id")
    var teacherId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("schedule")
    var schedule: ArrayList<schedule?>? = null


) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class schedule(

    @field:SerializedName("event_id")
    var eventId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("schedule_time")
    var scheduleTime: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status")
    var status: String? = null
) : Parcelable
```

I'm using recyclerview to add element to arraylist. the element is data class model. And here's the flow first i get the data from API then display the data with recyclerview. and then after display i want take the display data and save it to array list. after save data to arraylist, the arraylist will send the data to api like this :

```
{
    "user_available_id": 702,
    "teacher_id" : 3207,
    "schedule" : [{
                "event_id" : 47533,
                "schedule_time" : "2020-11-30 07:00:00",
                "status" :1
             },
             {
                "event_id" : 47532,
                "schedule_time" : "2020-11-30 06:30:00",
                "status" :1
             }]
}
```

i'm struggling with the data that save to arraylist always overwrite the current data with new data when i add new data to arraylist.

**The Function**

```
  private suspend fun getMultiSlotJadwal(id: String, date: String) {
        jamList.clear()
        val networkConfig =
            NetworkConfig().getTeacher().getTeacherScheduleAvailability(token, id, date)

        if (networkConfig.isSuccessful) {

            if (networkConfig.body()!!.availability!!.isEmpty()) {

                binding.rvSlot.visibility = View.GONE
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Jam tidak tersedia",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            } else {
                for (slot in networkConfig.body()!!.availability!!) {

                    //convert tanggal start ke millis
                    val tanggalSlot = slot!!.start!!.toDate().formatTo("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
                    val tanggalInMillis = convertToMillis(tanggalSlot)

                    //ambil tanggal sekarang
                    val myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" // format tanggal
                    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                    val time = calendar.time
                    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
                    val curdate = sdf.format(time) //diconvert ke tanggal local
                    val curDateinMillis = convertToMillis(curdate) // convert ke millis

                    val hasilDate = tanggalInMillis - curDateinMillis
                    val tanggalJam = hasilDate / 3600000 //diubah dari millis ke jam

                    if (tanggalJam >= 6) {
                        jamList.add(slot)
                        val sortJamList = jamList.sortedBy { jamList -> jamList.start }
                       
                        binding.rvSlot.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                        val adapter = SlotJamMultiAdapter(sortJamList) {

                            teacher_id = it.teacherId.toString()

                            scheduleModel.userAvailableId = user_avalaible_id //model
                            scheduleModel.teacherId = teacher_id

                            scheduleItem.scheduleTime = it.start.toString()
                            scheduleItem.status = "1"
                            scheduleItem.eventId = it.id.toString()

                            scheduleList.add(scheduleItem) // array list

                            scheduleModel.schedule = scheduleList
                            Log.d(TAG, "getMultiSlotJadwal: $scheduleList")
                            itemClicked = true

                            changeBackgroundButtonSesi2()
                        }
                        adapter.submitList(sortJamList)
                        binding.rvSlot.adapter = adapter


                    }

                }
            }

        } else {

            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Jam tidak tersedia",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

***Edit***
here's my adapter after using diffutils
**Adapter**

```
class SlotJamMultiAdapter(
    private var data: List<AvailabilitySlotItem>,
    private val listener: (AvailabilitySlotItem) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SlotJamMultiAdapter.LeagueViewHolder>() {
    private lateinit var ContextAdapter: Context

    class LeagueViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val tvJam = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_slot_jam_list)
        val cvSlot = view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cv_slot_list)
        val llSlot = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.ll_cv_slot)

        fun bidnItem(
            data: AvailabilitySlotItem,
            listener: (AvailabilitySlotItem) -> Unit,
            context: Context,
            position: Int
        ) {
            val jam = data.start!!.toDate().formatTo("HH:mm")
            tvJam.text = jam

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener(data)

            }
        }

        private fun String.toDate(
            dateFormat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
        ): Date {
            val parser = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            parser.timeZone = timeZone
            return parser.parse(this)
        }

        private fun Date.formatTo(
            dateFormat: String,
            timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
        ): String {
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            formatter.timeZone = timeZone
            return formatter.format(this)
        }

    }

    class slotItemDiffCallback(
        var oldSlotList: List<AvailabilitySlotItem>,
        var newSlotList: List<AvailabilitySlotItem>
    ) : DiffUtil.Callback() {
        override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
            return oldSlotList.size
        }

        override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
            return newSlotList.size
        }

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return (oldSlotList.get(oldItemPosition).id == newSlotList.get(newItemPosition).id)
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldSlotList.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newSlotList.get(newItemPosition))
        }

    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): SlotJamMultiAdapter.LeagueViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        ContextAdapter = parent.context
        val inflatedView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slot_list, parent, false)
        return SlotJamMultiAdapter.LeagueViewHolder(inflatedView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SlotJamMultiAdapter.LeagueViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bidnItem(data[position], listener, ContextAdapter, position)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    fun submitList(availabilitySlotItemList: List<AvailabilitySlotItem>) {
        val oldList = data
        val diffResult:DiffUtil.DiffResult=DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
            slotItemDiffCallback(
                oldList,availabilitySlotItemList
            )
        )
        data = availabilitySlotItemList
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because every time you get the list with getMultiSlotJadwal(), You create a new adapter instance and assign it to the recyclerview.

```
 binding.rvSlot.adapter = SlotJamMultiAdapter(sortJamList) { }
```

Keep referencing the assigned adapter, and then when you get the new list from the server, provide the list to the adapter you were previously referencing.

You can search ListAdatper / DiffUtil.Callback, they check if the items in the new list are the same items in the old list on behalf of you. All you have to do is submit the new list to the `ListAdapter` like below

```
 val newList = getNewListFromServer()
 myAdapter.submitList(list)
```

Updated

Ok, for the ScheduleModel

```
class ScheduleModel(
    val userAvailableId : String?,
    val teacherId : String?,
    val schedule : List<String>?
) {

    class ScheduleDiffUtilCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ScheduleModel>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ScheduleModel, newItem: ScheduleModel): Boolean {
            return true
            // set the way how to identify if the newItem is the same as the oldItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ScheduleModel, newItem: ScheduleModel): Boolean {
            return true
            // set the way how to identify if the newItem's contents is the same as the oldItem's contents
        }
    }
}
```

for the Adapter

```
class SlotJamMultiAdapter : ListAdapter<ScheduleModel, SlotJamMultiAdapter.ViewHolder>(
    ScheduleModel.ScheduleDiffUtilCallback()
){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_schedule, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    class ViewHolder(root : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(root) {
        fun bind(item : ScheduleModel) {
            //bind data to view here
        }
    }
}
```

Node that you don't actually reference data list yourself in the adapter class. ListAdapter will do reference it and do all the thing you need for updating data.

All you have to do is, in fragment or activity

```
   val adapter = SlotJamMultiAdapter()
   rc.adapter = adapter
```

And when your data changes(if you get the new list)

```
   adapter.submitList(newList)
```

Note that I didn't create a new Adapter instance, I am referencing the old adapter that was attached to the recyclerview, and I am reusing it

Comment: i'm sorry i dont really understand, my case is if i click the item and then add to arraylist. not when i hit the server and then add to arraylist. if the case with your answer is same with mine then should i add the DiffUtil to my adapter?

Comment: So you are adding a datum to the list that is bind to recyclerview, am I right?
Then, in your case, DiffUtil.Callback will solve your problem.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged will also work, but it's kind of a burden to do it.

Comment: hello SGTCheung, its still same, can you take a look i update my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224645/discussion-between-adytia-kresna-farisi-and-sgtcheung).